# How to set the number of threads dynamically and run the thread group in loop?

Tags: jmeter

I have one Thread Group. I want to run this thread in loop. First time the number of threads(users) should be 1, second time the number of thread should be 6( which means, for i=1;i=i+5;i<=25). Please note that the running thread group should be automatically.

What I have tried is, I did set the 'Counter' config element in which the 'start' is 1, 'increment' is 5, 'maximum' 25, 'number format' 00.

When I run the thread group, it runs only one time(number of threads(users) is 1) and it doesn't not continue with the next iteration.

Am i missing something? or is there any other way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't change number of users 'on fly'. The first thought is to write one test plan, ant build file and run the same test plan few time with different arguments, where argument will mean number of users. But you will need to write JMeter reports into different files. Example of running JMeter with argument is here: http://mkbansal.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/jmeter-command-line-script-execution-with-arguments/

Answer (score 1):

Hi the previous answer is correct, but a little bit cumbersome to execute.

IMHO, the simplest way to get that is to install the jmeter-plugins add on from "http://jmeter-plugins.org".

There are several useful add on, and a couple that may solve your needs, namely: "stepping thread group" and "ultimate thread group" if you want something even more flexible.

Comment: Thanks, but, I followed the steps as first answer. I just created shell and batch script to run the script by passing the no.of threads in for loop. At this moment, this is enough for me. However, I am going to try these plugins when optimization is needed.